# Create a shortcode in Wordpress, again

Tags: shortcode

There're lots of examples both here and on the internet, I've tried but don't seem to be able to achieve what I need although it does feel like it should be simple enough.

Basically, I want to be able to use a shortcode like this:

```
[download]http://site.com/file.doc[/download]
```

and I need Wordpress to output this:

```
<a class="download" href="http://site.com/file.doc">download file</a>
<a class="download" href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://site.com/file.doc">preview file</a>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: What's your problem in creating that shortcode? What have you done so far? Please add the code you've done so far and explain the problem you've run into.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How do I create short codes for my wordpress themes?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/how-do-i-create-short-codes-for-my-wordpress-themes) -  it explains how to create a shortcode and has example code in it's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Declare your shortcode
add_shortcode("download", "downloadFunction");

// Second Declare your shortcode function
function downloadFunction($att, $content, $code){

    // your function is passed 3 Arguments
    // $atts : this is an array of the shortcode's attributes
    // $content : this is the content between the code. in your case the file url.
    // $code : this is the code used. in this case it will be download.
    // here we only need the $content of the shortcode which we place for the file

$return = '<a class="download" href="'.$content.'">download file</a>';
$return .= '<a class="download" href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url='.$content.'">preview file</a>';

// we then return the result.
return $return;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, it works perfectly. i'm sure i'll be able to take it from there and expand it if needed. @hakre, thanks for the link, too.