# How do I create a widget to embed the code for a sign up form, so that the sign up form appears on every page?

Tags: widgets

I'm going to follow the instructions here: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-add-my-signup-form-on-my-website to create a sign up form on my website.

I think I need to embed the code that I generate when I follow those instructions in to a widget.

How do I create a widget to embed the code in to?

And once I've created a widget and added the code for the sign up form, will the sign up form appear on every page on my site? Including blog posts?

If not, how can I make it appear on every page? And how do I make it also appear on every blog post?

I'm using a modified Twenty Eleven Child theme on this site: http://richardclunan.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to create a Widget, just enable the Shortcode capability to the default Text widget.

Add this to the child theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Then you can proceed to create a Shortcode that will render the form.
See: [How do I create shortcodes for my wordpress themes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3804/12615)

The appearance of the Widget in every page will depend on your theme's implementation of `get_sidebar()` and its widgets areas. But much probably yes, it'll appear everywhere. *Does other widgets appear everywhere you want?*